# Unable to resolve DNS for kubernetes cluster on Ubuntu only

Tags: networking, dns, curl, kubernetes

I've been reading through the forums all day and can't find an answer to this so I'm hoping I can get help here.

I've setup a kubernetes cluster with DNS using a CNAME to point it to my cluster as per the providers docs:

https://cms.jwnwilson-kube.co.uk/

I can access this no problem on my windows machine or mac laptop but it's not possible on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop.

- All other sites resolve correctly on Ubuntu.
- nslookup works but not curl
- I've tried all the various solutions of updating my /etc/resolv.conf settings to 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4. but had no luck.

Any help with my Ubuntu or DNS settings would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just setup an A record instead which which is less flexible but I have no idea what else to do for Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I just setup an A record instead which which is less flexible but I have no idea what else to do for Ubuntu, CNAME only records don't seem to resolve correctly.